# Why Force.com - Enterprise Edition (Light Applications) 10 object limit doesn't apply?

Tags: custom-object, force.com, licenses, platform-license

We are currently using Force.com - Enterprise Edition (Light Application), this is what it's called in the contract, but in Company overview it's called Force.com - App Subscription. From what I've searched so far, Salesforce Limits the access to 10 Custom Objects. Excluding access to Standard objects, the profiles created for this license on our org has access to around 20 Custom objects and I have confirmed that the users can access all of them. Does any of you know how this 10 Custom Object access limit apply? or if am I understanding this wrong?

Answer (score 3):

This limit is enforced contractually. If Salesforce audits your org's usage of these licenses, they may not be happy about it